# .Net Core project Nuget Packages Can not restore

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I want to restore my Identity Server 4 project, after open VS2017 but when package manager try to restore references, it gets fail error every time.

I use latest version of VS2017 and my core packages installed and updated on my pc.

**Error     The feed 'nuget.org [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json]' lists package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.2.1.3' but multiple attempts to download the nupkg have failed. The feed is either invalid or required packages were removed while the current operation was in progress. Verify the package exists on the feed and try again.
Unable to find package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.2.1.3'.**

[image]

Comment: Where did you meet this issue, VSTS or local?

Comment: VSTS project. Download to source code from TFS and try to first restore, then crash.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You mean that you pull the project from TFS to the local and restore it on local, and then get this error? If yes, have you use Manager nuget packages UI to check if you can find that package? And if you can open the source '[https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json]' in the browser directly?

Comment: Yes i can open directly this latest packages source url and another v2 old one. I use Nuget Packages Manager UI and get same error again. Can i found nuget event logs or detailed exception log anywhere, is it possible ?

Comment: i added detailed error screenshot main part of the question. you can see it.

Comment: Yes, I have seen it. Thanks. What have you done, then you got that error? Are you using any command line or nuget package manager UI to install any nuget package?

Comment: I have never done anything, this is empty project. I created new project and first of all try to install some packages on Nuget UI or Console, then i get this error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the message in the error log:

> end of central directory record could not be found

You can try the following troubleshooting steps to resolve this issue:

- Clean the entire NuGet package cache by the command:

  ```
  nuget locals all -clear
  ```
- Close all Visual Studio instances, delete the `nuget.config` file in the location:

  ```
  C:\Users\leoliu\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
  ```

  and then reopen Visual Studio to restore NuGet packages.
- Check if there is a firewall policy or other proxy settings that is blocking the NuGet installation package.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try it by **Manage NuGet Packages** ?

1) Remove IdentityServer4 from **Dependencies**

2) Open **Manage NuGet Packages**

3) Browse IdentityServer4 again and install it

[image]