# Nuget not installing packages

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

**Goal**

My goal is to simply install a package via NuGet Package Manager.

I decided to delete Visual Studio 2019 and re-install it. Hoping it'll solve my issue. Then, I created a new project - tried downloading a `Newtonsoft.Json` package and same errors are displayed.

**Error**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The feed 'nuget.org [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json]' lists package 'Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.1' but multiple attempts to download the nupkg have failed. The feed is either invalid or required packages were removed while the current operation was in progress. Verify the package exists on the feed and try again.
Unable to find package 'Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.1'.
```

**What I tried**

I tried the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52327750/12485722

It displays the same error again.

Also, have tried to install another package such as `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

I then took a look into the Output and this is displayed:

```
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/index.json 199ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/13.0.1/newtonsoft.json.13.0.1.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/13.0.1/newtonsoft.json.13.0.1.nupkg 1ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/13.0.1/newtonsoft.json.13.0.1.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/13.0.1/newtonsoft.json.13.0.1.nupkg 96ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/13.0.1/newtonsoft.json.13.0.1.nupkg
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/13.0.1/newtonsoft.json.13.0.1.nupkg 96ms
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/index.json 498ms
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/index.json
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/newtonsoft.json/index.json
The feed 'nuget.org [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json]' lists package 'Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.1' but multiple attempts to download the nupkg have failed. The feed is either invalid or required packages were removed while the current operation was in progress. Verify the package exists on the feed and try again.
  Unable to find package 'Newtonsoft.Json.13.0.1'.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.9643895
```

I also followed steps from the Microsoft website *(Quick solution for Visual Studio users)* : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore-troubleshooting

Nothing changed.

Why is my NuGet Packages not installing?

**NuGet.Config**

This is how my *NuGet.Config* looks like. Found in `C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This appears to be a network problem. Can you manually download the package from nuget.org?

Comment: @PMF Manually, downloads without a problem.

Comment: And other packages show the same behavior (you didn't write that above)?

Comment: @PMF Other packages manually downloads fine. But, using the NuGet via Visual Studio displays the same error.

Comment: After running `nuget locals all -clear` make sure you also clean your output (i.e `git clean -dfX`, `git clean -dfx`). And close all instances of VS first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the steps I did to make it work.

```
Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings
```

Go into `Package Sources`

Copy the details of `nuget.org`

Delete `nuget.org`

Then, re-add `nuget.org` using the details you copied.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer, this will benefit other forum members. Thanks for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar problems, I was trying to install packages through Package Manager, clicked agree and it just flashed but did nothing - and the "install" button was still active.

When I tried to install the packages manually I finally got the error that I was installing for the wrong version of .net

My Target Framework was net6.0 and I was trying to install a package net8.0 - stupid mistake but when I changed the target framework it installed fine.