# Unable to install nuget package due to bad request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, nuget

Today I want to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation).

But it turns out I get bad request for

```sh
https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.runtimecompilation/5.0.10/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.runtimecompilation.5.0.10.nupkg
```

And it said

> "The feed 'nuget.org [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json]' lists package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.5.0.10' but multiple attempts to download the nupkg have failed. The feed is either invalid or required packages were removed while the current operation was in progress. Verify the package exists on the feed and try again.
> Unable to find package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation.5.0.10'."

I have checked that package source is from

```sh
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52327750/12351609).

Just like [Leo Liu-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7460777/leo-liu-msft) said:

- Clean the entire NuGet package cache by the command:

  ```
  nuget locals all -clear
  ```
- Close all Visual Studio instances, delete the `nuget.config` file in the location:

  ```
  C:\Users\leoliu\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
  ```

  and then reopen Visual Studio to restore NuGet packages.
- Check if there is a firewall policy or other proxy settings that is blocking the NuGet installation package.

Comment: I followed the process but still get the same result.

Comment: Are you using any VPN? Also, if you right click on the solution and click "Manage Nuget Packages", have you selected "nuget.org" in "package source"?

Comment: I tried to change to another ISP and it all works well.

Comment: So maybe the problem is from ISP.