# The feed 'nuget.org [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json]' lists package 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.4.14.0' but multiple attempts to download

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I tried to download the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer But this problem appears before the download of the package is finished,
Please can you tell me how I solve this problem?

```
Error:The feed 'nuget.org [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json]' lists package 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.4.14.0' but multiple attempts to download the nupkg have failed. The feed is either invalid or required packages were removed while the current operation was in progress. Verify the package exists on the feed and try again.
Unable to find package 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.4.14.0'.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net Core project Nuget Packages Can not restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52298073/net-core-project-nuget-packages-can-not-restore)

Comment: Try disabling all other nuget package sources inside Options.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work!

Comment: Did you try ping `https://api.nuget.org` on machine where you have this error?

Comment: I downloaded other packages and it works, but this package shows the above problem